# UILabel text pushed down out the bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

When I launch the application from Xcode I receive this result. No matter on simulator or device.
[no issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mx4MQ.jpg)

When I launch the application from the device desktop, my labels text pushed down the borders of the label

[with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU9eR.jpg)

Can smb explain why is this happened? And how to resolve this problem?

Labels populated with attributed text. I check that with simple string this issue is also reproduced.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: @aheze yes, constraints are set with auto layout

Answer (score 1):

Still don't know why this issue is occurred, but I resolved it by setting labels numberOfLines = 2